# Upi Payments in Flutter using Deep link (Android and IOS)

Tags: flutter, payment, paytm, upi

## **Gateway**: **Paytm Business for payments**

Hi I am trying to implement Upi payments in flutter using Deep link.

I don't want to use any thrid party libraries like Upi_pay etc.

**Deep link: paytmmp://pay?pa=paytm-67035308@paytm&pn=Reciver_NAME&mc=5812&tid=PYTM3101623366056793109&tr=3101623366056793109&am=3&cu=INR**

I am using launchUrl to initiate transaction

```
bool launchResult = await launchUrl(deep_link_url);
print('******************');
print(launchResult);
print('******************');
if (launchResult) {
  //verifyTransaction
} else {
  //'Could not inititate transaction');
}
```

After launching the URL, I have integrated the Paytm API to verify the transaction status. **My intention is for the flow to seamlessly return to my app once the transaction is completed. Following the return to my app, I aim to check the status of the transaction. How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Hi Vamshi, have you been able to achieve this? Currently, I have fetched the list of installed UPI apps on the user's device through native code and method channel. After generating this Paytm link, I want to open the app that has already been selected. It would be great if you could share your experience.